# How we can find table names on which query was running in DB2 Activity Event Monitoring?

Tags: database, db2

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1401sqltrace/index.html

I am using the above link for DB2 Monitoring. I need the table name on which query is running. Is there any direct way to find the table name not from the full query statement.

Answer (score 0):

Query can use multiple tables. If you want to have a full list of tables participating in a query, you can use explain tables for this:

Use one of the [Explain routines](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/c0061228.html) - (EXPLAIN_FROM_*) depending on the source of your query (package cache, event monitor tables, catalog) to get an access plan of your query.
Use the [EXPLAIN_OBJECT](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001100.html) table afterwards to find all the objects used by your query including tables.

Comment: I am able to find out activity type,username,time started and the by using below query.select activity_type,session_auth_id,tpmon_client_wkstn,time_started,stmt_text
from sqltrace.activity_trace_evmon  a
left outer join  sqltrace.activitystmt_trace_evmon b on 
a.PARTITION_NUMBER=b.PARTITION_NUMBER and a.APPL_ID=b.APPL_ID and  a.UOW_ID=b.UOW_ID and a.ACTIVITY_ID=b.ACTIVITY_ID order by time_started desc; Now i want the all tables used in stmt_text's query in the single column

Comment: You must create explain tables if you haven't done this earlier. For example, with the following db2 call: "call sysinstallobjects('C', 'EXPLAIN', null, user)".
Then you call the [EXPLAIN_FROM_ACTIVITY](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0056203.html) routine with parameters corresponding to your activity.
Your explain tables are populated afterwards, and you can find the information you need in the EXPLAIN_OBJECT table.